# How can I partially deserialize a JSON string using Jackson library?

Tags: java

The scenario is the following:
I have a jsons string.

```
  JSONContent=  {
        "elemA":"valA",
        "elemB":{
            "elemC":"valC"  
        }
    }
```

How can i deserialize  only the element emelB without having to deserialize  its parent?

What i've tried so far is the code below. It will return an object elemB having its elemC=null.

```
ObjectMapper mObjectMapper;  mObjectMapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
mObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

ElemB elemB = mObjectMapper.readValue(JSONContent, ElemB.class);


Where the classes def is:

class Parent{
    String elemA;
    ElemB elemB;

    //setters & getters
}
class ElemB{
    String elemC;
    //setters & getters
}
```

If i'll deserialize the whole parent content, everything will be fine. But I don't want this.

Thanks.

PS: For clearness purposes I've provided a very simple JSON. In my side I'm dealing with a much complex JSON. That is why I just want to have it partially deserialize.
Also I don't really want to come up with a method that will extract only the JSON part i'm interested in and then feed it to the objectmappr.

Comment: It seems that Jackson is at a low level a streaming (StAX-style API). Maybe poke around the javadocs and see if you can create an object mapper by passing it a low-level stream? Then you could open the stream yourself, pass all events until `elemB`, feed the partially read event stream to the mapper, and hope for the best. (If that doesn't work you could maybe create your own event stream implementation that filters the original - discard all until the starting `{` after `elemB`, then count matching braces and stop reading after you find the final `}` of that element.)

Comment: That said, I'll admit I'm mostly extrapolating from what StAX itself can do.